# Why does fast enumeration not skip the NSNumbers when I specify NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, fast-enumeration

I thought that I knew how to use fast enumeration, but there is something I don't understand about it. If I create three `NSString` objects and three `NSNumber` objects and put them in an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSString *str1 = @"str1";
NSString *str2 = @"str2";
NSString *str3 = @"str3";

NSNumber *nb1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *nb2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
NSNumber *nb3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:str1, str2, str3, nb1, nb2, nb3, nil];
```

then I make do fast enumeration on all `NSString` objects, like this:

```
for (NSString *str in array) {
    NSLog(@"str : %@", str);
}
```

In the console, I get this result :

```
2011-08-02 13:53:12.873 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : str1
2011-08-02 13:53:12.874 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : str2
2011-08-02 13:53:12.875 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : str3
2011-08-02 13:53:12.875 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : 1
2011-08-02 13:53:12.876 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : 2
2011-08-02 13:53:12.876 FastEnumeration[14172:b603] str : 3
```

I logged only the `NSString`s, but I get a line for every object in the array, even the `NSNumber`s and I don't understand why. Does fast enumeration always use every object contained in an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write a forin loop like that, it casts every object in the array as an NSString, then prints them out as requested.

If you want only the NSStrings, you would need to write something like this:

```
for (id obj in array) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"str: %@", obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: More precisely, it casts the *pointer* to be an NSString *pointer*. The object itself is unaffected.

Comment: Casting doesn't exist in Objective-C, only in C. An object thus can't be casted to another class. The type given in the fast enumeration doesn't change anything, every object is passed in. However, `NSLog` does "cast" using the object's `description` method. `NSString` just returns the string, `NSNumber` returns the string equivalent of the number.

Answer (score 8):

The `for all` loop doesn't know the difference between NSStrings and Integers -- it will simply go through the entire array, cast each as an NSString, and print them out as you asked.

Comment: The only reason the code does not crash is that NSLog does not care if you are passing it an NSNumber or NSString when printing.

Comment: @Kendall Helmstetter Gelner - Good point.  Do you know if the values get cast in some way or another?

Comment: @Chris Gregg: If by "the values," you mean the objects themselves, no, there's no such thing as casting an object in Objective-C. Remember, you never actually deal with object values directly in Objective-C. You refer to objects through pointers. Casting from one pointer type to another doesn't change the memory being pointed to — it just tells the compiler to assume there's a different type at the pointed-to address.

Comment: @Chuck - got it.  I assume, then, that `NSLog()` has to first figure out what the class of the object is before it prints it to the console?  I guess that is true whenever you use the `%@` format; correct me if I'm wrong, but under the covers whatever function is utilizing `%@` will first call `NSObject`'s `- (NSString *)description` method?

Comment: @Chris Gregg: Actually, `NSLog()` doesn't need to know anything about the argument beyond the fact that it's an object — as you correctly note, `NSLog()` just sends `description` to the object and prints whatever string that returns. That process doesn't require `NSLog()` or the argument to know anything about each other; they just need to know that `description` returns a string.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure that fast enumeration returns all objects in the array- all that you're doing in `for (NSString *str in array)` is typecasting `str` to an `NSString`. In the body of the loop you need to check the class of the returned object to make sure that it is an `NSString`.

```
for(NSString *str in array)
{
    if([str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        NSLog(@"str : %@", str);
}
```

Comment: You're completely right. Too bad your answer has lower votes than the wrong answers…

Comment: @Kiwiiz'Apps Can you mark this answer as the right one? It would help a lot of people. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSString *str in array) {
```

is a way to enumerate through all the elements in array.

You expectative that by specifying `NSString` you get only the objects of that type is not correct. Rather, all the objects pointers are cast to that type (`NSString*`).

Have a look at [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) in The Objective-C Programming Language guide.

Comment: Casting doesn't exist in Objective-C, only in C. An object thus can't be casted to another class. The type given in the fast enumeration doesn't change anything, every object is passed in. However, `NSLog` does "cast" using the object's `description` method. `NSString` just returns the string, `NSNumber` returns the string equivalent of the number.

Comment: @Randy Marsh, thanks for your comment. Indeed, what I meant is that the pointer is cast from `id` to `NSString*`; only, my wording was not proper.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is dynamically typed, meaning that at runtime (when the loop actually runs), objects are all effectively one type (`id`) with different classes. The language allows optional compile-time static typing, but all that does is check whether the messages you're sending are valid for the type you've marked. It doesn't actually change the behavior of your program. If you cast an object to be a different type than it actually is, all you're doing is lying to the compiler and defeating its type-checker.

Answer (score 1):

Every object that descends from NSObject implements the method - (NSString)description, %@ in Objective-C formate string will take the corresponding argument for the %@ and call its description method, Most subclasses of NSObject will implement there own version of - (NSString)description. The same thing happens when you type

```
> po anObject
```

in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where is the unexpected behavior, using the enhanced for loop in an `NSMutableArray` will just iterate thru every single object in the array which in your case is 6, the result is correct and expected.

The numbers will just get casted to Strings.

Answer (score 0):

in fast enumeration no typecasting,just assigning the pointer into new object