# What actually happens during fast enumeration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, casting, enumeration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does fast enumeration not skip the NSNumbers when I specify NSStrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918620/why-does-fast-enumeration-not-skip-the-nsnumbers-when-i-specify-nsstrings)

I noticed some unexpected behavior while using fast enumeration recently. In hindsight I was probably expecting fast enumeration to do more than it's intended for, so I'm looking for some clarification on how it's actually works.

Say I have a parent class **Shape** with 2 child classes, **3SidedShape** and **4SidedShape**. I have an array called **myShapes**, that contains objects from both the 3 and 4 sided classes.

If I wanted to search through the array **myShapes**, but I'm only concerned with 3 sides shapes what I was doing is:

```
 for (3SidedShape *shape in myShapes)
```

My thought was that I would only be iterating over objects of class **3SidedShape**, but that is not the case? I guess I'm casting all objects as **3SidedShape** whether they like it or not. I'm evening returning the object after as a completely different class. Granted I'm not calling any methods that both classes don't have, but I didn't expect class siblings to just re-cast so easily without a hitch? Did I just get lucky here or can you really enumerate as any class you please regardless of relation? Can anyone explain what actually happens during enumeration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast enumeration on NSArray of different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452505/fast-enumeration-on-nsarray-of-different-types), [fast enumeration objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918620/fast-enumeration-objective-c),

Comment: That's the way it works.  Best to have your variable declared as the common supertype (`(id)` if necessary) and then test it's type and cast to the correct type.

Comment: I think @Metabble's answer tells you what you need to know.  But if you really want to understand what fast enumeration does “under the covers”, check out [this article by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html).

Comment: @robmayoff +1 for the link. Bookmarked for later reading.

Comment: If you know C an easy way to understand why they "recast so easily" is to look at the types from a C perspective and remembering that `id` is in fact `void*`. Fast enumeration simply yields an id and that _casts_ to your object as easily as a `void*` _casts_ to an `int*` regardless of what the address originated as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type specified in a *for...in* loop, aka fast enumeration, casts all the elements in the collection to the specified type. The reason why they are "re-cast so easily" is that casting does NOT turn one type of object into another (how would that work?). It's a hint to the compiler telling it to treat the object as if it were the other type, as if to say "don't worry, this object is of *(insert type)*, so type check it as such." Sending the object a message it can't handle, but the type it was casted to can, will still crash the app. What you should do is this:

```
for (id shape in myShapes){
    if ([shape isKindOfClass: [3SidedShape class]]){
        //insert code here
    }
}
```

That code assumes nothing of type, using [introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Introspection.html) to only perform the code for objects who are of type *3SidedShape* or a subclass of *3SidedShape*. For exact checking (excluding subclasses) use *isMemberOfClass:*. Be wary of using *isMemberOfClass:* to test membership of a class in a class cluster (NSNumber), however, due to their more complex internal implementation.

Comment: You probably don't want a pointer to id in your enumeration variable.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for pointing that out! I wrote it as 3SidedShape originally (which would require the asterisk) and changed it to id, thus the little guy got forgotten about. Editing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like it was wishful thinking on my part thinking the object was being converted. It's the casting that was tripping me up. I'm coming from a database background where you can cast a char as a int, so I was thinking of it in a similar way. Where the result was slightly modified.

I guess I should be looking at casting as more of a managerial process to help me handle objects, but not change them.

Comment: You're welcome. Although casting can't convert between two types of objects, it still has its uses, such as casting an id back to whatever type it really is. Also, one way to use casting other than in a purely managerial way is in casting primitive types. Ex. a float or double to an integer to truncate it. You could use _floor()_, but _floor()_ truncates towards negative infinity, while _(int)_ truncates towards zero (which is probably what you want most of the time).